# Using shortestpathpointtopoint tool with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, parameters

I am a total beginner with Python and programming in GIS in general. I have point data and I want to compare in which month people walked the longest distance.
It is a relative large dataset and I want to do it relatively automatically.
This is my approach:

```py
import processing

layer_anfang = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("MVG_2016_Wetter_Januar")[0]
layer_ende = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("MVG_2016_wetter_januar_ende")[0]

for i in range(0, 5):    
    startlat = layer_anfang.getFeature(i).attribute(3)
    startlon = layer_anfang.getFeature(i).attribute(4)
    endlat = layer_ende.getFeature(i).attribute(5)
    endlon = layer_ende.getFeature(i).attribute(6)

    x = startlon, startlat, endlon, endlat
    print(x)

processing.run("native:shortestpathpointtopoint", \
{'INPUT':'C:\\Users\\.......', \
'STRATEGY':0,'DIRECTION_FIELD':'','VALUE_FORWARD':'','VALUE_BACKWARD':'','VALUE_BOTH':'','DEFAULT_DIRECTION':2,'SPEED_FIELD':'','DEFAULT_SPEED':50,'TOLERANCE':0, \
'START_POINT':'startlon, startlat [EPSG:4326]','END_POINT':' 11.47498, 48.10944 [EPSG:4326]',\
'OUTPUT':'C:/Users/.....'})
```

The plan is to iterate over the attribute table and get the lon/lat data from my attribute table and then parse it into the parameters for `"START POINT"` and `"END_POINT"`. As you can see in this example I did it for the `Start_Point`, the `END_Point` is as it was before. I always get the error `wrong parameter for START_Point`, even though, if I print it for example it is in the right style.

Must I cast any datatype or something on the variable or is this all complete wrong?

Comment: Where does Start_Point come from? It's not in your code, as we can't say why it's not working. Also, you have "START POINT", Start_Point and START_Point. Make up your mind :-)

Answer (score 5):

For `'START_POINT'` parameter (and `'END_POINT'` parameter if necessary), use this:

```
'START_POINT': f"{startlon},{startlat} [EPSG:4326]",
'END_POINT': f"{endlon},{endlat} [EPSG:4326]"
```

I guess, `processing.run` should be located in `for` loop.

```
import processing

layer_anfang = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("MVG_2016_Wetter_Januar")[0]
layer_ende = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("MVG_2016_wetter_januar_ende")[0]

for i in range(0, 5):    
    startlat = layer_anfang.getFeature(i).attribute(3)
    startlon = layer_anfang.getFeature(i).attribute(4)
    endlat = layer_ende.getFeature(i).attribute(5)
    endlon = layer_ende.getFeature(i).attribute(6)

    x = startlon, startlat, endlon, endlat
    print(x)

    processing.run("native:shortestpathpointtopoint", 
                   {'INPUT':'C:\\Users\\.......', 
                    'STRATEGY':0,
                    'DIRECTION_FIELD':'',
                    'VALUE_FORWARD':'',
                    'VALUE_BACKWARD':'',
                    'VALUE_BOTH':'',
                    'DEFAULT_DIRECTION':2,
                    'SPEED_FIELD':'',
                    'DEFAULT_SPEED':50,
                    'TOLERANCE':0, 
                    'START_POINT': f"{startlon},{startlat} [EPSG:4326]",
                    'END_POINT': f"{endlon},{endlat} [EPSG:4326]",
                    'OUTPUT':'C:/Users/.....'})
```